# Elastic chord in a soap solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, elasticity, surface-tension

> A film of soap solution of surface tensions $ \sigma$ is made in a cirular wire frame of radius r, two diametrically opposite points A and B of which are connected by a thin and light elastic chord of Young's Modulus *Y* and area of cross section *S*. If the film on one side of the chord is punctured, find elongation in the elastic thread. (use $ 
> \arcsin(\theta) \approx \theta + \frac{\theta^3}{6} $)

While solving this question i made an assumption that the remaining part of the soap solution along with the thread would assume a circular surface but I couldnt deduce how I would proceed further with the problem. I tried considering an element and an angle of deviation $\theta$ from the horizontal of the ring but I was slightly confused on what to do next.

The book has given the answer to be $ \left(\frac{16 \sigma^2 r^5}{3Y^2S^2}\right)^\frac{1}{3} $

Comment: Suppose you had a horizontal clothesline that is initially carrying no load, and you apply a uniformly distributed load vertically on the clothesline.  Could you determine the downward displacement dietribution of the clothesline, and its tension distribution?